ROS Installaion on Windows - Please provide credentials for: http://aka.ms/ros/public
Following the instructions to install ROS on windows from the site - https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows 
Step 5 involves adding a new source for chocolatey - https://aka.ms/ros/public 
But it seems to require credentials
ros-noetic-desktop_full is not installed. Installing.......
Invalid credentials specified.
Please provide credentials for: http://aka.ms/ros/public
User name: 
Password:

Is this a bug? 
There are no instructions on how to access packages in this choco source.. 
Should we register at any site for obtaining these credentials?

Answering my own question - for anyone that stumbles on this problem.It appears that this was a temporary bug of some sort.
It failed to work for a few days, then rectified on its own.
C:\opt>choco upgrade ros-noetic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
ros-noetic-desktop_full
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
ros-noetic-desktop_full is not installed. Installing...
Progress: Downloading ros-noetic-desktop_full 20201214.0.0.2104301300... 100%

ros-noetic-desktop_full v20201214.0.0.2104301300
ros-noetic-desktop_full package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing ros-noetic-desktop_full...
ros-noetic-desktop_full has been installed.
  ros-noetic-desktop_full can be automatically uninstalled.
 The upgrade of ros-noetic-desktop_full was successful.
  Software installed to 'c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\'

Chocolatey upgraded 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (c:\opt\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

